# Linear approximation $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

The question I'm trying to solve is

Find the linear approximation to the function defined by $f(x, y, z) = (zy^3, xe^x +y +z)$
at the point $(0, 1, 1)$.

If this was $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ then I would get the gradient and from that get the equation for the tangent plane. Does the same process apply here? If so, how do I get the gradient for $\mathbb R^3 \to\mathbb  R^2$?

Comment: How about linearly approximating the two functions $f_1(x, y, z) = zy^3$ and $f_2(x, y, z) = xe^x + y + z$, and then putting the two approximations together?

Answer (score 0):

The linear approximation is $$L(x,y,z)=f(0,1,1)+f'(0,1,1)\,(x,y,z)^T,$$where $f'$ is the (Fréchet) derivative
$$
f'(a,b,c)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(a,b,c)&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(a,b,c)&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}(a,b,c) \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(a,b,c)&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}(a,b,c)&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z}(a,b,c) \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This is the unique linear transformation $T$ such that 
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|f((a,b,c)+h)-f(a,b,c)-Th\|}{\|h\|}=0.
$$